# Play MovieClip frame by frame in addition after same function is executed several times

Tags: actionscript-3, function, frame, addition, movieclip

I have a MovieClip named fails_mc, it consists of 3 soccer balls and in my game  every time my player fails I need to add an X mark over 1 ball, I have a hitTestObject detecting when the ball hits the goal area, but when the ball goes outside I need to play 1 frame inside the fails_mc and add the X mark to a ball ( I have 3 different png files inside fails_mc, 1 on each frame), this is the code I’m using but I don’t know how to play frame by frame the fails_mc (keep in mind that the same function will be used every time, that’s why each frame must be added to the last played frame:

```
if (ball.hitTestObject(goalie))
{
    goal_mc.play();
    net_mc.play();
}
else
{
    fails_mc.play(+=1); // This is not working

    trace("It’s a fail");
}
```

After 3 fails I must trigger another function that will finish the game but I will figure out how to do that later on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think all your looking for is the nextFrame() function of a movieClip.

you could also use gotoAndStop("x1") - where "x1" is the frame label (or number if not in quotes) you want the movieClip to goto.  You could use a variable to track the current state.

```
var misses:int = 0;

if (ball.hitTestObject(goalie))
{

    goal_mc.play();
    net_mc.play();

}
else
{
    misses++;
    trace("It’s a fail");

    if(misses > 3){
        //do your game over stuff
    }else{
        fails_mc.gotoAndStop(misses)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks LondonDrugs, fails_mc.gotoAndStop(2); worked perfectly, however the next time the function is executed I need to go and play the next frame, game should finish when player misses 3 shoots but the function executed will be the same, so I need to know how to play +1 frame till 3 balls are X marked. Thanks pal!

Comment: wow that worked LondonDrugs, but I think that my code is adding too many misses , probably because of an enterframe event, if I upload my .fla file would you mind to take a look? really appreciated buddy I'm kindda lost here