# Need to increase var value by +1 and it is increasing multiple times during same function AS3- Please check my code

Tags: actionscript-3, function, addition, trace

Could you please take a look to my code below, I need to increase the var misses by 1 every time the ball does not hit the goal area (it’s a penalty shootout game) but the matter is that it increases many times, this is the output message after making a trace for the variable value so you can have an idea:

It's a fail 1
1
It's a fail 2
2
It's a fail 3
3
It's a fail 4
4
It's a fail 5
5
It's a fail 6
6
It's a fail 7
7
It's a fail 8
8
It's a fail 9
9
It's a fail 10
10
And so on, my code is this and I’m pretty sure that the line affecting the result needed is the line stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnter);  could you please give me some advice on how to work around this? Probably trying an alternative way to move the ball when is is moved in moveBall function? I have received a lot of help from you guys and I’m sorry for being so annoying, simply I’m still a newbie and get stuck at some points between my code and the ideas I have gathered so far. Here is my code

```
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.ui.Mouse;
import flash.geom.Point;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

 var misses:int= 0;//Here the var used trying to put the game over when player misses 3 shoots
var cursor:MovieClip; // mouse will be converted to a cursor (aim) which is the spot ball must follow
var nowX:Number; ;// will be used to move the ball
var nowY:Number;// will be used to move the ball
var isUpdating:Boolean = false; // will be used to control mouse events and other later on
var isClipSync:Boolean = false; // will be used to control mouse events and other later on
const START_BALL_POINT:Point = new Point(296,353); // returning the ball to original positions
function initializeGame():void
 {   
cursor = new Cursor();
addChild(cursor);
cursor.enabled = false;
//Mouse.hide(); 
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, dragCursor);
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, onCursorMove);
  }

  function onCursorMove(e:MouseEvent):void
  {
cursor.x = mouseX;
cursor.y = mouseY;
 }

function onEnter(e:Event):void
{
 isUpdating= true;

 if(pateador_mc.currentFrame == 19) 
 {
     pateador_mc.gotoAndStop(1);
 }
 //trace(pateador_mc.currentFrame);
 //

if(pateador_mc.currentFrame > 11)
    isClipSync = true;

 moveBall();
  }


  function dragCursor(event:MouseEvent):void
 {
if(isUpdating) return;

trace(isUpdating);
nowX = mouseX;
nowY = mouseY;

pateador_mc.play();
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnter);// probably this is causing        multiple count of trace events when I try to gather the failed shoots
}

initializeGame();
var mouse=this.Mouse;

var speed:int = 800;
var ease:int = 4;
 var gravity:Number = 0.5;
function moveBall()
  {
if(!isClipSync) return;

bola.x += 0.2 * (nowX - bola.x);
bola.y += 0.2 * (nowY - bola.y);

if(Math.abs(nowX-bola.x)<1 && Math.abs(nowY-bola.y)<1) 
{
    stage.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnter);
    isUpdating = false;
    isClipSync = false;
    var timer3:Timer = new Timer(3000,1);
    timer3.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, accionRepetida3);
    timer3.start();
    function accionRepetida3(e:TimerEvent)
    {
    bola.x = START_BALL_POINT.x;
    bola.y = START_BALL_POINT.y;}
}
if (bola.hitTestObject(goalie))
{

    gol_mc.play();  /// All good at this point
    red_mc.play();

}
//
  else
{

    misses++;
    trace("It's a fail", misses);


}

 }
```

I will really appreciate if some good pal takes the time to check on this, I promise when I get a better programmer I will help all those who need it.

Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you modify your code and give the output again?

```
trace("It's a fail for barrier3", misses)
trace("It's a fail for barrier2", misses) and so on.
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Alpera, really appreciated man, actually a simple else statement will do the trick for what I'm looking for, I was playing with some barrier objects to see if putting an object for collision things will change, however both options have the same result, hope you can help me. I already made the change to the code putting a simple else statement. output will be the same It's a fail 1, It's a fail 2 and so on. I just need  3 additions to the original 0 value finishing with 3 misses. Check original question here

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11974731/1567903, could upload .fla in case you want to take a look

Comment: are you calling moveball in a loop? i couldn't fully understand your code. the error is probably because of incrementing misses for each movement of the ball.

Comment: yes that's probably the problem Alpera, thanks a lot for your help, here is full file probably you could make a test man, I´ll owe you big time [File .fla](https://rapidshare.com/files/3696681055/kicks.fla)

Comment: thanx for uploading but i can't deal with fla files now. i don't have flash installed. i can only say try this, tray that.. for now.

Comment: consider having a boolean variable for incrementing, for example: var increment: false, make it true while you start moving the ball, when you first increment misses (misses++), set it false again, and always check if it is true before incrementing. by this you will avoid extra increments.

Comment: Thanks again alpera, that makes sense, will try that hopefully that will make the tick. Have a great night pal!

Comment: you're welcome. actually sun is just rised here, but a great night to you too :)

Comment: Wow, well have a good day then my friend, thanks for your help the boolean stuff worked nicely!